# How derivative relates to roots of original function

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Assume $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that for any $ k \in \mathbb{R}$, $f' + kf$ has a root between any two distinct roots of $f$.

I am completely stumped on this. What are some good ways to show existence of zeros? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to do this problem, admittedly. But here are my thoughts - existence of zeros? This makes me think Intermediate Value Theorem, Rolle's Theorem, or Mean Value Theorem. Since $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Try playing around with that.

Comment: Rolle's Theorem is applicable for k=0.

Comment: The principal difficulty is that $f'$ is not necessarily continuous, so the obvious application of the intermediate value theorem does not work.

Comment: Here is my rough attempt (I don't know whether it is correct):
Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $f$ such that there are not roots in $(\alpha,\beta)$. Assume on the contrary that $f'+kf$ has no roots in $(\alpha,\beta)$. We assume that $f'+kf>0$. By checking $f'$ at $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we come to a conclusion that $f$ must have a root in $(\alpha,\beta)$ due to continuity of $f$, which is a contradiction to $f$ not having any roots in $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: If f has roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$, then we can apply the idea to each separate intervals and restrict these intervals if necessary. For instance, to check whether $f'+kf$ has a root in $(\alpha,\gamma)$ we can apply the idea to either $(\alpha,\beta)$ or $(\beta,\gamma)$.

Comment: @Novice What do you mean check $f'$ at $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @DHH Since $f'+kf>0$, substitute $\alpha$ and $\beta$ into this equation will result $f'>0$, since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $f$.

Comment: @Novice when you say if $f' + kf$ has no roots, you then assume $f' + kf > 0$ on the interval. But the expression could change sign, couldn't it? If it were continuous, then you could apply the IVT, but otherwise there's no telling..

Comment: @maxerize you are right. $f'+kf$ need not be continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution (I asked someone for help with it):

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two distinct roots of $f$. Consider $g = e^{kx}f$. Then note that $g' = ke^{kx}f + e^{kx} f'$. By Rolle's theorem, since $g(\alpha)=g(\beta)=0$, there exists a $c \in (\alpha, \beta)$ such that $g'=0$ $\implies$ $f'(c)+kf(c)=0$.

Comment: Very clever and well done, worthy of the old ***plus one!!!*** / And if you lie my comment's rhyme, I'll try to do it every time!  Cheers!